# How can I hide some navbar pages when a non-admin user is logged-in in the admin panel?

Tags: php, html, css, validation

What I do is to put all these

nav-item

(there are about five of these links) inside the navbar.php and just add <?php include(navbar.html) in all those five page so that everytime I click page 1,2,3,.4 or 5th webpage, the nav bar still can be seen. But when the "User" (non-admin user) logged in, I don't want to include the page 1 on his navbar because that page has features for admin only, which is what I'm having a problem with....

Index.php

```
<?php
include('includes/navbar.php');
?>

<!-- Main Content  -->

<?php
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
include('includes/navbar.php');
?>

<!-- Main Content  -->

<?php
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

page3.php

```
<?php
include('includes/navbar.php');
?>

<!-- Main Content  -->

<?php
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

page4.php

```
<?php
include('includes/navbar.php');
?>

<!-- Main Content  -->

<?php
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

Page5.php

```
<?php
include('includes/navbar.php');
?>

<!-- Main Content  -->

<?php
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

code.php  Here is the code where for validating if the user is an admin or non-admin user
The !password_verify is for validation for password and hash password.

```
if(isset($_POST['login_btn']))
{
    $email_login = $_POST['emaill']; 
    $password_login = $_POST['passwordd']; 
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='$email_login' LIMIT 1";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $password = "SELECT password FROM register WHERE email='$email_login'";
    $usertypes = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run);

   if($usertypes['usertype'] == "admin")
   {
    if(!password_verify($password_login, $password))
    {   
        $_SESSION['username'] = $usertypes['username'];
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else
    {
         $_SESSION['status'] = "Email / Password is Invalid";
         header('Location: login.php');
    }
   } 
   else if  ($usertypes['usertype'] == "user")
   {
    if(!password_verify($password_login, $password)){   
        $_SESSION['username'] = $usertypes['username'];
        header('Location: index2.php');
    }
    else
    {
         $_SESSION['status'] = "Email / Password is Invalid";
         header('Location: login.php');
    }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:**  I've already found a solution to the problem... Just put all the list items tag`<li></li>` inside this php elseif if you want to display a specific navbar list when an Admin user is logged in but want to hide them in a non-admin one.

```
<?php if($_SESSION['TYPE'] == 'admin'): ?>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="PageForAdmin.php">
        <i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size: 20px;"></i>
        <span>Page For Admin</span></a>
</li>

<?php endif;  ?>
```

Comment: You should first check how the rest of CMS works to do this type of things, the easy thing is to add an extra column to your user table like `admin` with `1 or 0` value and check it when you render your navbar.

Comment: Using a session would be helpful. You can use a simple if/else statement to detect if the user is the admin. Here is a link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Sorry I've just edited my post and at the bottom, you can see there the session for login and I want to know how can I add the validations for hiding some navbar pages in that code or dunno if I should put it somewhere else.

Comment: Please be warned that your query is widely open for SQL injection. Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry for the late response; I've just updated my post and I include my solution there, it's in the bottom of my post. Also, thank you for the warning.  I'll try to fix it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **if else** loop
For Laravel

```
@if(Auth::user()->user_role == "role")
// Show page 1
@else
// show page 2
@endif
```

**For you**

```html
<?php

if ($user->role == 'admin'){
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="page1.php">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        <span>Page1</span></a>
</li>

   
 }else {
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="page.php">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        <span>Page2</span></a>
</li>

 }

?>
```

**May be code not compiled**

```
<?php

if ($user->role == "admin"){
```

If You use number then

```
<?php

if ($user->role == 1){
```

**Note:** This is a example you can use it. I not tested it. Use how you want to use `role` or **usertype** at the `if` condition

```
<?php
    
    if ($usertype->username == "admin){
```

**Example For 5 Page**

```html
<?php

if ($user->role == 'admin'){
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="page1.php">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        <span>Page1</span></a>
</li>

   
 }else if ($user->role == 'author'){
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="page.php">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        <span>Page2</span></a>
</li>

 

 }else if ($user->role == 'editor'){
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="page.php">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        <span>Page3</span></a>
</li>

  }else if ($user->role == 'superadmin'){
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="page.php">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        <span>Page4</span></a>
</li>

 }else if ($user->role == 'superadmin2'){
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="page.php">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        <span>Page5</span></a>
</li>

 }
?>
```

You can use nested `if` `else` or `elseif` too Like you can use next if in firstone's else like see below code

```html
<?php

if ($user->role == 'admin'){
  // your query

   
 }else 

 if ($user->role == 'author'){
   // your query
 }else 
 if ($user->role == 'admin2'){
    // your query

 }else 
 if($user->role == 'admin1'){
    // your query
 }

 

 }
?>
```

Comment: What should I do if I have 5 pages and I only want to remove 1 of those for the non admin user? should I copy all those 4 <li></li> inside the if $user == 'admin' ?


Also after redirecting to the index.php, it's still have a navbar.php included on it, should I remove it and just rely on the <li> </li> inside the if else ?

Comment: Hi I updte my post above (it is on the bottom of my post) I want to say that the code that you post is only for the index page itself (Page 1) where all this nav list will show up and will not be included in those page 2,3,4,5 so what I do is to put all these <li></li> inside the navbar.php and just add <?php include(navbar.html) in all those five page so  that everytime I click page 1,2,3,.4 or 5th webpage, the nav bar still can be seen. But when the "User" (non-admin) logged in, I don't want to include the page 1 on  his navbar because that page has features for admin only,which is my prob..

Comment: use if else loop in nav bar tooo, it's was an example for page but you can apply on anywhere.